# Unable to slice strings retrieved from div's

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, slice

I'm having trouble slicing text I retrieved from a div with javascript/jquery. I thought you could slice every string and that the .text() function always returned a string so I fail to see the problem. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7m3a2fpg/4/)

Html:

```
<body>
<div class="vaknaam">Div 1 :<span class="totaal">55%</span>

</div>
<div class="vaknaam">Div 2 :<span class="totaal">60%</span>

</div>
<div class="vaknaam">Div 3 :<span class="totaal">64%</span>

</div>
<div class="vaknaam">Div 4 :<span class="totaal">76%</span>

</div>
<div class="vaknaam">Div 5 :<span class="totaal">63%</span>

</div>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function () {
var divs = {};
var tempString, vakken = {};
$('.vaknaam').each(function (key, value) {
  tempString = $(value).contents().filter(function () {
      return this.nodeType == 3;
  }).text();
  tempString = tempString.slice(0, - 2);
  vakken[tempString] = $(value).children('span').text();
 });

for (var property in vakken) {
  $('body').append("<p>" + property + "</p>");
}
});
```

Comment: You're ignoring the return value of the `.slice()` call.

Comment: I'd just chain it on to the end of `.text()`... so `...text().slice(0, -2)`

Comment: Please note, your question would be a a lot easier to understand if you posted *working* (at least up to where you are having the problem) code. In your fiddle you don't include jQuery and `vakken` isn't defined. These kind of things make it more difficult to get to your *actual* problem.

Comment: ...oh, and you'll also need to `$.trim()` the text if you were looking to get rid of the `:`. You've not actually told us what the expected output is.

Comment: I fixed the fiddle. I'm sorry for my mistake.
I am filtering the text nodes because it's actually the : i was hoping to get rid off.

Comment: You still have no `vakken` variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several errors.

1. You need to declare an initialise the var `vakken`.
2. The `slice` method does not modify the string so you should assign what returns to something.
3. `property` var is just an index so you need to ask for `vakken[property]`

Your code should look like this:

```
$(function () {
  var divs = {};
  var tempString, vakken = {}; //1
  $('.vaknaam').each(function (key, value) {
      tempString = $(value).contents().filter(function () {
          return this.nodeType == 3;
      }).text();
      tempString = tempString.slice(0, -4); //2
      vakken[tempString] = $(value).children('span').text();
  });

  for (var property in vakken) {
      $('body').append("<p>" + property + "</p>"); //3
  }
});
```

Check out this [codepen](http://codepen.io/ianaya89/pen/xbKobO).

Comment: You are right but I want the property to be printed and not the value of it in vakken. And if you append the property, you see that the string hasn't been sliced.

Comment: Sorry I'm lost, could you show me an example of what you want to print?

Comment: Div 1
Div 2
Div 3
...
Without the ': ' at the end.

Comment: Ok, so just replace the slice param -2 by -4: tempString = tempString.slice(0, -4); . (I have updated the code)

Comment: Hmm, I see it works on your codepen. It doesn't work with my fiddle unfortunately. Is this a bug of fiddle?

Comment: It does work when I trim it first like @squint suggested above, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

`slice` doesn't modify the initial string, which is immutable. Try:

```
tempString = tempString.slice(0, - 2);
```

Comment: It fixes the slice issue but the code still has errors.